# Trouble getting to value in this array with php

Tags: php

I want to get to the order number for each array set. But I cannot seem to get to this.
When I can get a sample part of this array:

```
Array Dump:
<?php
$data =
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'orderId' => 577633674,
     'orderNumber' => '2939',
     'orderKey' => '2939',
     'orderDate' => '2020-07-28T00:00:00.0000000',
     'createDate' => '2020-07-28T10:58:35.3600000',
     'modifyDate' => '2020-10-20T06:39:30.0070000',
     'paymentDate' => '2020-07-28T10:58:34.0000000',
     'shipByDate' => NULL,
     'orderStatus' => 'awaiting_shipment',
     'customerId' => 309926130,
     'customerUsername' => 'REMOVED',
     'customerEmail' => 'REMOVED',
     'billTo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'name' => 'REMOVED',
       'company' => '',
       'street1' => 'REMOVED, ',
       'street2' => 'REMOVED',
       'street3' => '',
       'city' => 'Austin',
       'state' => 'TX',
       'postalCode' => 'REMOVED',
       'country' => '  ',
       'phone' => 'REMOVED',
       'residential' => NULL,
       'addressVerified' => NULL,
    )),
```

But I am uncertain how I can get to orderNumber.

I have tried `var_dump($orders["data"]["0"]["stdClass::__set_state"]["orderNumber"]);` But this is returning null. I am a little lost as to how to get to this data.

Comment: `$data[0]->orderNumber`

Comment: Thats it! TY TY TY!